# How to add rel="author" attribute to Drupal 7?

Tags: 7

In the brave new world of Google, great integration with Google+ is mandatory for all webmasters who want to get as much traffic as possible. If adding the `rel="publisher"` attribute to a website is done with the Meta Tags module, it seems that there's no official way for supporting the rel="author" attribute. For those of you who don't know about I am talking about, read this article from Google: [Author information in search results](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1408986)

Apparently support will be included in Drupal 8. I've seen some discussions about adding this to the Drupal 8 core.

But how to implement this in Drupal 7?

I am asking this as a noob in customizing the insides of Drupal. So, if you have some good ideas, please keep this in mind.

Appreciate your ideas.

Comment: Do you want this added to the head section of the page as a meta tag?

Comment: Yes. That's how it should be done, according to Google. For each article, you insert the link towards the Google+ profile of that author.

Comment: According to Google Authorship markup is no longer supported in web search since August 2014. See more here https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6083347?hl=en and here https://plus.google.com/+JohnMueller/posts/HZf3KDP1Dm8

Answer (score 8):

The rel=author property is now supported by the Drupal 7 Metatags module dev version.

After installing the metatags module (http://drupal.org/project/metatag), go to admin/config/search/metatags, and edit the front-page or one of the node pages. Under 'Advanced' you will see the author and publisher fields where you can input your google+ page URL. On the following screenshot, I've marked the places you need to change the configuration in pink.

**Metatags frontpage configuration page:**

[image: Here is my screenshot - configuration is marked in pink]

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, way less complicated to make a token and have people input it this way.

Answer (score 5):

Using ideas from the `rdf_preprocess_node()` function that Dave Hall linked you could implement it this way (code goes into your theme's template.php file):

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['page']) {
    $account = user_load($variables['uid']);
    $title = $account->name;

    $author_info = array(
      '#tag' => 'link',
      '#attributes' => array(
        'rel' => 'author',
        'href' => 'http://localhost',
        'title' => $title,
      ),
    );

    drupal_add_html_head($author_info, 'author');
  }
}
```

This adds the necessary link into the head section of full node pages. I used the node author's id to get the necessary user data. You'd probably want to add a website field for users that you could use here to get a complete solution.

Comment: So, i should add a field for each user where the Google+ Profile link information is stored? Also, sorry for my ignorance here - is there a specific name I should give to that field?

Comment: @CorporateGeek Yeah I think that would be a good approach and the field name doesn't really matter. The [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module seems to be suitable for the field addition. I might be off here, but you could probably use `$page = $account->field_myfieldname['und'][0]['value'];` to get the value later in the code to add it to the 'href' attribute.

Comment: There is actually no need for the Profile2 module in Drupal 7 as field support for users comes with core already (admin/config/people/accounts/fields).

Comment: This is an excellent approach. The only thing I changed was to use `if ($node = menu_get_object()) { if($node->type == "blog") { ...` to test for my blog content type. Thanks! I also like the idea of adding a field for the G+ URL if there's more than one user on a site, that way it's fully dynamic.

Answer (score 4):

Implementing hook_preprocess_node() in a module or your theme should do it.  Check out the rdf module's implementation for some inspiration.  http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--rdf--rdf.module/function/rdf_preprocess_node/7

Comment: Is it possible to provide a bit more guidance, for the folks who are not really technical?

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party, but I'm answering this for people who land on this page in search of a solution.

There is now a [Google Authorship module](http://drupal.org/project/google_authorship).

Answer (score 0):

```
function themename_preprocess_username(&$vars) {
  // Username is linked, use the link_attributes to inject the rel attribute
  if (isset($vars['link_path'])) {
    $vars['link_attributes']['rel'][] = 'author';
  }
  // Username is NOT linked, use the attributes_array to inject the rel attribute
  else {
    $vars['attributes_array']['rel'][] = 'author';
  }
}
```