# Google Rich Snippets and Facebook Open Metagraph

Tags: social-network, 7, rdf

I want to implement support for [Google Rich Snippets](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170) to show author info and fivestar ratings in Google's search engine results pages. I also want to be able to support [Facebook's Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) to have Facebook pick the correct image when a node with an image is "liked" or embedded on Facebook.

Looks like I can use [Schema.org](http://drupal.org/project/schemaorg), [microdata](http://drupal.org/project/microdata) or [RDFx](http://drupal.org/project/rdfx) modules. I also came across a post [suggesting to just use a preprocess hook](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19710/how-to-add-rel-author-attribute-to-drupal-7).

The schema.org module doesn't seem to support fivestar ratings. Microdata is relatively new and I'm a bit confused about the RDFX module.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

In the answer above, there are modules indicated. However, in my experience, they won't work with fivestar, for they are only generic. So, what I usually do in such cases, is to:

1. Create a template for that node type, like *node--type.tpl.php*
2. Create a preprocess function in your theme's *template.php* file, implementing [hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7)(). This will translate to an actual function name like *mytheme_preprocess_node(&Svariables)*.
3. In that function, use the *$variables['node']* to get the data from the fivestar widget field.
4. Format and prepare that data for output, and add your custom variables to the *$variables* array.
5. Use the variables you provided in your preprocess function to insert the correct markup in your node file to correspond to the opengraph / rich snippets format.

Some notes:

1. Use [devel module](https://drupal.org/project/devel) and *dpm()* function to dump the *$variables* in preprocess function and the data in the template file.
2. Use the [google markup tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) and the [facebook markup tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to test your markup.
3. The logic is, prepare variables in preprocess, and put them in markup in template file. Try not to have computations (business logic) in the template file itself, use preprocess for it.

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/project/opengraph_meta -> it will take the image associated with node or you can specify a default

http://drupal.org/project/richsnippets ->Google Rich Snippets