# Integrate fivestar module with schemaorg module

Tags: 7, rating, rdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Rich Snippets and Facebook Open Metagraph](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51474/google-rich-snippets-and-facebook-open-metagraph)

I am using D7. I have a content type with a field of type [fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar). I am using [schemaorg](http://drupal.org/project/schemaorg) module to add RDFa to the HTML markup.

However fivestar doesn't work with schemaorg out of the box. I tried using [microdata](http://drupal.org/project/microdata) which claims to support fivestar but it didn't. I read in some forum/issue that the dev version is currently worked upon to support fivestar and still has issues.

I need help on integrating schemaorg module with fivestar. Anybody out there who has done this or something similar?