# How to add rel=author when you have "multiple authors" in one site?

Tags: 7, meta-tags

I would like to use Google rel=author meta tag, but I do have several authors writing in one site. I have a Drupal 7 site. Should I add a different authorship for each author?
How should I manage in that case?

I was planning to use [meta tags module](http://drupal.org/project/metatag), ([as explained here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19710/how-to-add-rel-author-attribute-to-drupal-7)) but the only way it seems to modify all urls in order to affect different url with different meta tags.
ie: /authorname/title that way, with different urls I could create different meta tags.

Could that be a normal procedure? Or there´s another way to add the author´s context?
Or maybe you just should use one single author and avoid multiplying authorship altogether?

**Ps. I don´t think this is a duplicated post**, because this one refers about multiple authors, instead of just asking how to implement rel=author in D7.

Comment: [Doesn't seem like it's possible.](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25140/how-to-implement-rel-author-on-a-page-with-multiple-authors)

Comment: Thanks for your comment (it didn´t occurr to me that I could consult webmasters forum too dóh :). But my case is slightly different: I run a website with several authors, but each "link" has a single author. 
The thing is that I would like to concentrate all pages into a big "author" that´s the site name itself. As I believe I can´t do that I thought could just create a specific rel=author for each author, for each individual webpage.

Comment: If it's only one author per article then you can set the author on the node level using Metatags, as described [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/62417/5612).

Answer (score 1):

This is simple.

- Add a text field to the user profile at /admin/config/people/accounts/fields and call it Google Profile (or similar).
- Go to the Metatag configuration page and look up the token for Google Profile.
- Add this token to the Author Metatag for the relevent content type(s). The token for my setup is: [node:author:field_google_profile]
- Have every author load their Google+ profile to this field in their user profile.

[EDIT] It's worth noting that Google no longer uses rel=author as a ranking factor, so this discussion is now purely academic.

Regards

David

Comment: Thanks! It looks like that´s the only available solution, to have single pages with specific authors... (How about the homepage with a sinopsis and a link to every autor latest article?)